# Excel function to transpose every nth row into columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, offset

I have a sheet with a large row of data but the relevant data are every 3rd row

In Sheet1

| Col A |
| --- |
| First |
| Second |
| Third |
| Fourth |
| Fifth |
| Sixth |
| Seventh |

In Sheet2, I would like to transpose the relevant rows to update automatically as column headers, i.e.,

| First | Fourth | Seventh |
| --- | --- | --- |

I tried a variety of offset/transpose etc. functions, but I always seems to get it updating the column (so as I drag the formula it would change A1 to B1 and so forth, but I want it to do A1 to A4 to A7 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=TOROW(FILTER(A1:A7,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A7))-1,3)=0))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=TOROW(IFS(MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A7))-1,3)=0,A1:A7),3)
```

---

For older versions :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,
  (ROW($A$1:$A$7)-ROW($A$1)+1)/(MOD(ROW($A$1:$A$7)-1,3)=0),
  COLUMN(A1)))
```

---

Note : Approaches shown above doesn't uses any **volatile functions**, since **volatile functions**(viz. <kbd>OFFSET()</kbd> & <kbd>INDIRECT()</kbd> ), it does not just recalculate anytime something on the sheet changes, it will recalculate anytime anything on any open excel workbook changes!

---

Another nice alternative suggested by **[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)** Sir.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(n,3,TOROW(TAKE(WRAPROWS(A1:A7,n),,1)))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=TAKE(WRAPCOLS(A1:A7,3),1)
```

---

Comment: Other variations:
`=index(Sheet1!A:A,{1,4,7})` or `=TAKE(WRAPCOLS(Sheet1!1:A11,3),1)`

Comment: @P.b Sir, `TOROW()` needs to be wrapped in `=TOROW(TAKE(WRAPROWS(A1:A7,3),,1))` and this one should'nt be `=index(Sheet1!A:A,{1,4,7})`

Comment: @P.b Sir, nevermind i have just added the second one, first one is hardcoded. Thanks for the great idea!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya this worked perfectly thank you.

Comment: Great thanks for the reminder I have done so.

Answer (score 0):

Type in B1

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(COLUMN(B1)-1)*3+1)
```

and copy paste to the right.

If the result need in another sheet then in cell A1 on sheet2

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(COLUMN(B1)-2)*3+1)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: The question was about referring to a different sheet, so you should take that in the indirect reference. While this would work well, this is a volatile solution, meaning it'll recalculate each time anything is changed within the file (even a random cell selection).
For this reason it's better to avoid the use of INDIRECT, or OFFSET whenever possible. 
Since we know exactly where we refer to, we can use your logic inside INDEX rather than INDIRECT: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*3+1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following formula in C1 you will get the requested outcome.

```
=OFFSET($A$1,3*(COLUMN()-COLUMN($C$2)),0)
```

If you want the output-table in another location, just change the `$C$2` accordingly. C2 was just selected to "follow" the formula correctly if used a different place

[image]

Comment: See my comment at Black Cat's solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you type `=transpose(A1:A10)` selecting B1:K1 and validating with `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER` it will do something you like.
when success validating, the formula will be updated and look like `{=transpose(A1:A10)}` (matrix).

[image]